# "Hide from Browser" Lists - Removes from Search Crawl

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search

Can anyone confirm that normal behaviour is when a list is "hidden from browser" it removes it from the Search Crawl.. This is what is happening to me, is there a way to hide list but still have list to be part of search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Doing this :

1. Navigate to the site that contains the list or library that you want
   to change.
2. Locate and click the list or library you want to customize.
3. Click Site Actions, and then click Site Settings.
4. Under Site Administration, click Site Libraries and lists.
5. Click an item from the list, for example, Customize “Shared
       Documents.”
6. On the List Settings page, under General Settings, click Advanced
       settings.
7. In the Search section, under **Allow items from this document library
       to appear in search results**, select **Yes** to include all of the items
       in the list or library in search result or No to exclude all items
       from search results.

Comment: Hi Thanks, when not hidden all are set to Yes. Is there javascript code to toggle this option on a list when .set_hidden is true?.